# What does Ubuntu software center error "bad quality package " means?

Tags: software-center, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “bad quality” package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111959/what-is-a-bad-quality-package)

In 11.04, Ubuntu software center complains most of the .deb package as bad quality package including chrome from google. What does it means? How can I force software center to accept the package and move on with installation ?.