# What are the risks of installing a "bad quality" package?

Tags: installation, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “bad quality” package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111959/what-is-a-bad-quality-package)

When I try to install [sonic-visualiser_1.9cc-1_amd64.deb](http://www.sonicvisualiser.org/download.html) via the Software Center the following warning message is displayed:

> **The package is of bad quality**
>
> The installation of a package which violates the quality standards isn't allowed. This could cause serious problems on your computer. Please contact the person or organisation who provided this package file and include the details beneath.

```
Lintian check results for /home/ak/Downloads/sonic-visualiser_1.9cc-1_amd64.deb:
Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"HOME"} in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/lintian line 108.
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/ 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/bin/ 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/bin/sonic-visualiser 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/ 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/applications/ 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/applications/sonic-visualiser.desktop 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/doc/ 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/doc/sonic-visualiser/ 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/doc/sonic-visualiser/CHANGELOG 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/doc/sonic-visualiser/COPYING 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/doc/sonic-visualiser/README 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/mimelnk/ 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/mimelnk/application/ 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/mimelnk/application/x-sonicvisualiser-layer.desktop 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/mimelnk/application/x-sonicvisualiser.desktop 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/pixmaps/ 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/pixmaps/sv-icon-light.svg 1000/1000
E: sonic-visualiser: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/pixmaps/sv-icon.svg 1000/1000
```

I understand that this means the package [doesn't meet Debian policy](https://askubuntu.com/a/111992/1859) and I know how to override the warning and [install the package anyway](https://askubuntu.com/a/35133/1859).

What are the risks of doing so?

Comment: You might want to look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/111959/what-is-a-bad-quality-package