# I get 'package is of bad quality' error while installing CrossPlatformUI for MBlaze

Tags: 13.04

My system is 64-bit Ubuntu 13.04. I'm trying to connect through USB 3.0 port.
Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E1552/E1800/E173 (HSPA modem)
```

I want to access **MTS Mblaze** for internet. I was not able to create connection so I googled and found out that 'crossplatformui-v2.1.2-sstl-all-ubuntu.deb' would solve the problem.

I downloaded this package and tried to install but I'm getting **Package is of bad quality** error.

Comment: also related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/117928/what-are-the-risks-of-installing-a-bad-quality-package