# The package is of bad quality - google chrome

Tags: installation, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “bad quality” package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111959/what-is-a-bad-quality-package)

I'm doing a fresh install of 12.10 and am trying to install Google Chrome. I've downloaded the deb from http://chrome.google.com and am installing it through the Ubuntu Software Centre.

I'm getting a message:

```
The package is of bad quality
```

(same as [What is a "bad quality" package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111959/what-is-a-bad-quality-package))

In the expanded section, the "error" states:

```
E: google-chrome-stable: file-in-etc-not-marked-as-conffile etc/cron.daily/google-chrome
```

Is it safe to click on the "Ignore and Install" button?

Comment: As far as I know, perfectly safe.

Comment: did you try "dpkg -i your_deb_file.deb" instead?

Comment: Just as an aside, does it need to be Google Chrome? Chromium, the open source browser developed by Google as the foundation of Chrome is available in the Software Centre. Version-wise, it may not be the most bleeding edge available, but you'll have less problems if you use that.

Comment: Chromium doesn't work with Netflix, as it doesn't bundle windevine.

Comment: @Sirber while I appreciate the comment this is a 3 year old thread, a lot has changed in both Ubuntu and Chromium. If you're having issues I'd recommend you ask a new question and see if others have some answers for you

Comment: I had this exact issue installing chrome on Ubuntu 15.10 (daily).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get such kind of errors when Ubuntu doesn't trust the package your are installing. This was a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptdaemon/+bug/712377) and fix has been released for the same.

You can safely click on **Ignore and install**(Do this only when you trust the package) and the other alternate way is to install the package via command line using

```
 sudo dpkg -i deb_package_name.deb
```

But make sure you have the dependencies installed for a clean installation.

Comment: This actually isn't that bug, but it's a fairly similar issue.