# Software center states "The package is of bad quality" - what does it mean?

Tags: software-center, packaging, deb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “bad quality” package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111959/what-is-a-bad-quality-package)

I'm trying to author a `.deb` package, and with the one I have now, when I install it on Ubuntu 12.10 I get the next error:

```
The package is of bad quality
```

But when I expand the details nothing is listed.

I want to post a screen-shot, but I'm not allowed as a new user.

Any ideas?